# Get table row values from edited rows only

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table which has 10 columns. 4 of them are editable. They are the 4th, 5th, 6th and 10th columns. In this table there are approximately 5000 rows.

What I want to achieve is to get only row values that are being edited. The user doesn't want to use checkboxes or edit buttons. I want to update multiple rows based on user activity on those rows.

What I have tried so far.

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected-row');  
});
```

In this approach I am changing `tr` background-color and applying the `selected-row` class but when I click on the date picker it takes it as `tr` click and it is changing the `selected-row` class again.

Is there any other better approach to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You want to exempt Datepicker control from the selection and apply the toggleClass to 9 remaining elements/columns in the row.

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () { 
      $(this).not("#datePicker").toggleClass('selected-row'); 
});
```

If you want to do something else with Datepicker element:

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () { 
      $(this).not($("#datePicker").doSomething()).toggleClass('selected-row'); 
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What I was looking for is Robus/Clean approach to get only Rows in Jquery whose values are being edited. So I came up with this approach as my Client doesn't want to use Checkboxes, Edit Buttons etc.